# adb devices no permission for RHEL5

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, adb, rhel5

I have installed ADT in my RHEL5 machine. Since its a virtual box and cannot detect an external device, I installed Oracle VM extension pack and the virtual machine is detecting the device. But, eclipse is not detecting the device and when I try to run adb devices it says ???? no permissions. I set 51-android.rules file with all the vendor names but still the adb devices command has permission issues.
I have even tried killing and restarting the server with sudo permissions but no use. It is detecting the device only once after running those commands.

Comment: [Here](http://ptspts.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html) is a helpful link but before that, have you tried to kill and restart the server?

Comment: I have tried the steps mentioned in the link, but still the error persists. When I try to run sudo service udev restart command it says 'Missing Service_URI environment variable'